# Problem with Aptana Studio & XULRunner 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, ubuntu, aptana, xulrunner

I recently installed Ubuntu Jaunty and I'm encountering a problem when I try to run Aptana Studio under it. Any interaction with the internal browser crashes the system. I checked the log and after some Googling came to the conclusion that it was crashing due to the incompatibilty with XULRunner 9.0 which is installed on my system. I followed a couple of solutions I came across and installed XULRunner 8.1 (to a different directory) and pointed the MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME enviornmental variable to that particular version, as suggested.

```
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner-8.1
```

However, the problem persists! When I `cd` into the xulrunner-8.1 directory and perform a `./xulrunner -v` it still lists it as being version 9! I can't uninstall 9.x as several other major packages depend on it, one of which is the version of Gnome I have installed.

This is my first time using Linux since I played around with RedHat 7.2 waybackwhen, so I'm probably forgetting to do something obvious. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Aptana on Ubuntu Jaunty as well and met with similar problems as yourself. This [thread](http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8008) solved my problem, and I always launch my Aptana from a startup script. Particularly, the post by 'stevewalker'. Just to post his startup script here:-

```
#!/bin/sh
MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner
if [ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME
fi
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/aptana/AptanaStudio $@
```

Hope this helps! =)